# Рисование на JFrame

Tags: java

Каким образом можно рисовать на JFrame? Нужно переопределить paint()? Если да, то как потом вызывать этот метод?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо как-то так:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class JFramePaint1 {
   public static void main(String[] a) {
      MyJFrame f = new MyJFrame();
      f.setTitle("Drawing Graphics in Frames");
      f.setBounds(100,50,500,300);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
   static class MyJFrame extends JFrame {
      public void paint(Graphics g) {
         g.drawRect(20,10,100,60);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: И каким образом затем вызывать paint()? Что вместо g подставлять?

Comment: Зачем вам вызывать paint()?

Comment: ОС сама вызывает paint и передаёт туда информацию о том где рисовать

Comment: вот тут разжовано для самых маленьких Урок №132. Java. Рисование в JFrame http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wx-VmvxuQDs

Comment: Ммм, острить не нужно. Как оказалось, paint() вообще не нужно переопределять.

Comment: да кстати вроде же ещё надо вызывать метод paint для родителя. или я чего путаю? хммм

Comment: код метода `paint` должен быть как минимум таким:

      public void paint(Graphics g) {
         super.paint(g);
         g.drawRect(20,10,100,60);
      }